# Reveal file for current source control diff in VSCode explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an easy way to reveal the file associated with the "Changes" diffs under the Source Control tab in VSCode?

I don't think the `Files: Reveal Active File in Side Bar` shortcut/action/command is useful here since this active file is a temp file and not a file in the project

Comment: What do you mean by `reveal`?  Open the file or what?

Comment: @Mark the diff of the file is open on the editor, and I want the the file it's related to be centered and highlighted in the explorer, similar to what the `Files: Reveal Active File in Side Bar` command does

Answer (score -1):

You can click the "go to file" icon at the top right of the page when viewing a git diff:

The icon in light mode: [image: go to file icon in light mode]

The icon in dark mode: [image: got to file icon in dark mode]

It will open the file itself.

The same button is available on the right of each entry in the source control pane's list of changed files (it's only visible once you mouseover the item entry).

---

If you want to reveal in the explorer a file that you're currently viewing a SCM diff for, I don't think there's a way to do that at the time of this writing. You'd have to first go to the file, and then reveal the file in the explorer.

Comment: Thats not what the user is asking, he means the other way around, a keyboard shortcut when you are looking at a file (NOT changes) and you want to focus the file on the "Source control" panel